# How to assign values to the variables of Process while starting a new instance without using a form

Tags: jbpm

We can assign values through the form in BPM but we have a complex structure with nesting objects and even may require CLOB data. What is the process to handle the same without forms in JBPM (6.3).

Is it possible to pass this values through xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any Object when start a process instance use KieSession.startProcess.
for example:

```
    KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

    // Init arguments
    Map<String, Object> processArgsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    processArgsMap.put("employee", "admin");
    processArgsMap.put("reason", "self evaluation");
    processArgsMap.put("performance", "GOOD");

    // Start process
    ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess(this.processDefinitionId, processArgsMap);
```